# excel data from asp

Tags: asp.net, excel

i have made a list of folders from my directory, to show as html.

What i want is to be able to read and write in excel.

now what am strugleing to do is put this code to get it as .xlsx. i have a excel file in my computer and want all the directories to go in that file..

I have been told **EPPlus** is the best solution. but am not sure how to implement this in the above code so my directories comes in excel rather than html.

any ideas/direction would be really helpful

Comment: If you want to write to an Excel sheet, I would look in to using EPPlus, it's (in my opinion) the best library out there for interfacing with Excel in C#. http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Comment: any idea how i can implement that to the way i set my List_Dirs. because some say to add database

Comment: Sure, I'll post a quick example.

Comment: A database is not necessary if using an Excel library such as EPPlus (which I also highly recommend).

Comment: What type of error are you getting ? Is it an exception ? Have you tries debugging your DataTable to make sure it is filled ?

Comment: at the moment i am getting a list of folder names. but to get it open in a excel i am having difficulties.

Comment: What type of difficulties ? We can hardly help you if we don't know more the error you are getting. Please edit your question to include a caption of the error or the format problems you are having.

Comment: there is no error, i just cant seem to edit this in excel (am junior programmer) am going around in circle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to go the route of EPPlus, first thing you need to do is add the EPPlus package to your solution. This can be achieved by doing one of the following:

- Opening up NuGet, searching for EPPlus in the gallery and installing it
- Opening up your Package Manager Console and typing `Install-Package EPPlus`
- Downloading the dll file and manually adding a reference to it in your project.

Then, in your code:

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestConsole {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            string[] directoryList = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Users\bblack\Temp\TestDirectories\");

            using (Stream file = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\bblack\Temp\testexcelfile.xlsx", FileMode.Create))
            using (ExcelPackage xl = new ExcelPackage(file)) {
                ExcelWorksheet sheet = xl.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

                for (int i = 1; i < directoryList.Count(); i++)
                    sheet.Cells[i, 1].Value = directoryList[i];

                xl.Save();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This

- Gets all the directories in the address provided to it.
- Creates a new `FileStream` where you want your Excel file to be
- Creates a new `ExcelPackage` based off of the `FileStream`
- Adds a new worksheet (there are zero by default) to the workbook in the `ExcelPackage`
- Iterates through `directoryList`, and for each string in there puts the value in a new cell

**it is important to note, that worksheet cell indexes are not zero-based, they start with a base index of 1**

*edit* Woops, forgot to close the stream, use this updated answer.

Comment: +1 It might be helpful for al123 to note that column and row numbers in EPPlus start with 1 instead of the traditional 0. For example, column 1 is column A.

Comment: i have few red lines which is not going, "using" the 2nd one, saying must be implictly converible to 'sytem.IDisposable  , also; wordbook, count, cells

Comment: using OfficeOpenXml;
using System.Linq;
also giving red lines :/ sorry to be a pain Ben!

Comment: Ah of course, I forgot to mention. You need to go into NuGet and install the EPPlus package to your project. Also, good point @mason.

Comment: iv added the epplus.dll to my bin folder, but still getting red lines

Comment: If you go the route of just adding the dll, you need to make a reference to it in your project manually. Right-click your project and select `Add > Reference...`, in the popup go to `Browse...` and click the `Browse...` button. Then navigate to your dll.

Comment: right thats helped, but am still getting red line for; using System.Linq; using, Workbook & Count

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54734/discussion-between-ben-black-and-al123).

Comment: @al123 Did you try what we suggested in chat (removing all references you put in to EPPlus and reinstalling via the Package Manager Console?)